# CSS Column priority with or without Absolute Positioning

Tags: css

There's got to be a better way.  I have a webpage with a top section that has a left, center, right section.  But when the screen size is less that 999px wide, I want the CENTER section to be on top, with left and right to be below it.  So, for:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="left">   left content  </div>
<div class="center"> center content</div>
<div class="right">  right content </div>
</div> <!--End Container -->
<div class="below">...
```

The standard CSS is just:

```
.container { width: 100%; background: yellow; position: relative; clear: all; }
.left {  width:25%; display: inline-block;  height: 200px; background: blue; }
.center { width: 48%; display: inline-block; height: 200px; background: orange; margin: 0 auto; }
.right { width: 25%; display: inline-block;  height: 200px;  background-color: #888; }
```

And then for less than 1000px:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 999px) {
 .center { width: 100%; top: 0px; z-index: 1; position: absolute; }
 .left { width: 49%;  top: 200px; position: absolute; left: 0px; }
 .right { width: 49%; top: 200px; position: absolute; right: 0px; }
```

This creates the effect I need. HOWEVER, the very next div of content, "Below" is covered over by the absolute divs, and all I've seen is putting in a margin-top and calculating the height.  That's just creating hack upon hack.

Is there a way to get the Center div in a three column section to be on top as I've mentioned without screwing up the divs below that container?

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS's z-index property.  That determines how sibling nodes are rendered on the page from top to bottom of the z axis (into the screen)

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: I don't see how this helps. Z-index is about stack order and I don't want them on top of one another.  I want them to arrange, not overlap.

Comment: So what you want it to have the following scenario:
When wide enough - show all three divs side by side.
When too narrow - Center div above, and left and right divs below.
Is that what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

### Using grid

I've attached code, hope you get on with it.

It's also in my codepen (https://codepen.io/omergal/pen/BXqEdx)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  background: lightblue;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
}
.left {
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
.center {
  height: 200px;
  background: orange;
}
.right {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #888;
}
.below {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: purple;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 999px) {
  .container {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
  .center {
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 3;
  }
  .left {
    grid-area: 2 / 1 / 2 / 2;
  }
  .right {
    grid-area: 2 / 2 / 2 / 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left"> left content </div>
  <div class="center"> center content</div>
  <div class="right"> right content </div>
</div>
<div class="below">below</div>
```